# How to order post with user last login?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm setting a page. How can I do to order the post by the last connection of each user.

I've tried to use `'orderby'=> 'user_last_login'` but don't work.
When I change `'order'=>'DESC' by 'ASC'`, it make change but I need to order by last user connection.

```
$normal_args = array(
            'offset' => $normal_offset,
            'post_type' => $taxonomy_profile_url,
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page - count($premium->posts),
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => 'premium', 'value' => '0', 'compare' => '=', 'type' => 'NUMERIC' ) )
        );
```

Comment: give more information on context (api, version, etc...) maybe :  'orderby' => array( 'user_last_login' => 'DESC')

Comment: 2nd) Searching for a message posted by date of last connection is inappropriate because sending a message requires a session where the user is logged in. then ... sort by 'date' desc or 'modified' desc is enough. I did not see in the doc of WP_Query information on the date of connection ... do you have a link to a documentation about "user_last_login" ?

Comment: I haven't like to a documentation about "user_last_login"  how I can do it ? In fact, modified isn't enough, because users often make a connection whithout make a change. This website is a directory, the aim is to order by last connections users because users want their post put at the top to attract clients. We need a rotation.

Comment: I Presume you use this : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: I looked at wp_query again with the meta-query, and I did not see anything about the user's last login. I think (maybe I'm wrong ...) you have to use a plug-in. See here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/last-login/

Comment: I add in function.php :

function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
update_user_meta( $user->ID, ‘last_login’, time() );
}
add_action( ‘wp_login’, ‘user_last_login’, 10, 2 );

/**
* Display last login time
*
*/

function lastlogin() {
$last_login = get_the_author_meta(‘last_login’);
$the_login_date = human_time_diff($last_login);
return $the_login_date;
}

/**
* Add Shortcode lastlogin
*
*/

add_shortcode(‘lastlogin’,’lastlogin’);

Comment: I use this type of pluggin, this plugin add the code I show you below. 
I use : https://wordpress.org/plugins/when-last-login/